# Constraint Layout - How to make an image view (frame) to move on whole screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout with card view like tinder. I have changed the size of that view and like can move (like/dislike). But image is getting cut(since its in the inner frame). I want to move the frame on whole screen manually.

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/root_content_list"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <in.zapr.onemedia.custom.ZTextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
            android:text="@string/card_title"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/cs_title"
            app:type_face="@string/font_heavy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <in.zapr.onemedia.custom.ZTextView
            android:id="@+id/headingTip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/card_tip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/cs_subtitle"
            app:type_face="@string/font_heavy"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/heading"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/heading"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heading"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading_content_selection"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_retry_content_selection"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/reload"/>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.45"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headingTip"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_container"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_content_available"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>

        <com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
                android:id="@+id/card_stack_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:clipToPadding="false">
        </com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ll_Next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_cardView"
            android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_floating"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/skip_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:fabSize="normal"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    app:useCompatPadding="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/onboarding_dislike"
                    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/maybe_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/onboarding_maybe"
                    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:fabSize="normal"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/like_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/onboarding_like"
                    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:fabSize="normal"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    app:useCompatPadding="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <in.zapr.onemedia.custom.ZTextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/tv_not_seen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/cs_not_seen"
                app:type_face="@string/font_heavy"
                android:text="@string/not_seen_text"
                android:layout_below="@id/ll_floating"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <in.zapr.onemedia.custom.ZButton
            android:id="@+id/ll_Next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_click_selector"
            android:text="@string/letsGo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:type_face="@string/font_black"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the issue
[image: issue_image]

The output of xml will me
[image: output of the xml]

I am using the CardStackView from here,

https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

Comment: try android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false" on ll_cardView and root_content_list

Comment: wow, thanks for prompt response. I was stuck on this since a day. You are a magician

Comment: also don't use Relative Layout in Constraint Layout. you can position all views with out additional containers

Comment: yeah, will work on that. Thanks, add it as answer, I will accept it

Comment: now the view move under the bottom layout (Relative layout) 
How to fix this

Comment: move cards container below buttons in xml or add elevation to card container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194001/discussion-between-narendra-pal-and-vladislav-shcherbakov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to `ll_cardView` and `root_content_list` this attributes

```
android:clipChildren="false" 
android:clipToPadding="false"
```